# i have oil in my radiator. where can it be coming from. 427 ci chevy

Tags: engine, oil-in-coolant

chevy 427 ci     had oil in radiator   had heads redone and surfaced   replaced with new head gaskets     still having same problem.    radiator has the 2 trans cooling lines only  no oil cooling lines   need some help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the vehicle this is in? Is it the original setup of the engine, or is the engine a transplant? Is this a BBC or LSx engine? If BBC, does it have aluminum or cast iron heads? If BBC, which generation of engine is it? MkIV or ?? When you had the heads redone, did you flush the cooling system?

Comment: 67 chevelle     transplant for 396 i imagine.   BBC  cast iron heads   not sure of generation  late 60"s--early 70"s??   yes did fluid cooling system    thanks alot for helping

Comment: Your engine would be a MkIV BBC. I'm assuming it's a standard height block (not a tall deck or truck block). There's no coolant in the oil, correct?

Comment: Are you sure it's motor oil and not transmission fluid?  Mixed with coolant they can look similar.  Any possibility of a cracked block?

Comment: yes   std height block. no coolant in oil.    tranny fluid is clear and full    oil was 2 qts down when i noticed the problem      when this first started a friend was driving the car and was over heating when he brought it back to me.  could it be a cracked head also? or just cracked block?   thanks

Comment: ok   i am convinced    block it is    thanks to everyone on this site.

Answer (score 1):

As with the SBC, there's no oil passages running up through the heads. All oil which flows to the top end is through the pushrods. There are flow passages back down, but there's basically no pressure there. IOW: a cracked head would not cause your problem. I've been beating my head for the past while trying to remember where an oil leak could cause it to go into the water ... the only place it could be coming from is from the block ... one of the oil galleys into a water jacket. That's a guess though. You'd have to tear down the block and get it pressure tested.

Comment: SBC?  BBC?  Unexplained abbreviations aren’t helpful here.   Okay to use abbreviations, Best practice is to explain all abbreviations When First Used (WFU). We all understand that abbreviations are commonly used, but can’t all aspiring mechanics and home mechanics (just learning) also benefit from visits to this site?